# Redirect to standard view from VF page with nooverride parameter in SF1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, pagereference

The view of my custom object is overwritten by a Visualforce page for my desktop users. This VF page should not be visible for my mobile users.

Before I render my VF page, I check the device to redirect my mobile users like this:

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Travel__c" extensions="TravelCtrlExt" action="{!doDeviceDetection}">
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference doDeviceDetection() {

        PageReference result = null;

        Boolean isMobileDevice = false;
        String userAgent = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('USER-AGENT');

        if( (userAgent.contains('iPhone')) || (userAgent.contains('iPad')) || (userAgent.contains('Android')) ) {
            isMobileDevice = true;
        }

        if( isMobileDevice ) {
           result = stdCtrl.view();
           result.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');

        }

        return result;   
    }
```

This should redirect my mobile users to the standard view of the record, but it doesn't work.
The mobile users get stuck in a loop.

Comment: This was a bug that I recently submitted a fix for. Is it still happening?

Comment: @KrisGray sure, it's still happening. Where did you submit the fix ?

Comment: Next release, the one going out in a few weeks. Sandboxes should already have the fix.

Comment: @KrisGray Do you have a source for that, for example a note in the release notes ?

Comment: I don't participate in the release notes portion so I don't. The issue seems small enough that it wouldn't get documented.

Comment: This should work now right? Can it be closed?

Comment: Yes it's fixed, but I realized that you should not use PageReferences in Salesforce1.

Comment: I've been experiencing same issue. Can someone confirm if it is being reproduced again? My code involve showing Standard Edit screen of an sObject record, on Salesforce1, which has been overrided with a VF page for normal browser mode access. But "nooverride=1" parameter to URL is not working in S1, in mobile app, it just keep redirecting in a loop :( ...

Comment: @VarunC I'm having the exact same issue as you. It's going into a loop if used on the Edit screen. I've also tried the Javascript options using sforce.one.editRecord with the same problem

Comment: @VarunC - Did you ever manage a workaround for this? We're coming across the same problem with a conditional override based upon RecordType

Comment: No, the only workaround was to remove nooverride hack and compromise with a VF page for edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Bug is fixed now, thanks [@Kris Gray](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/138/kris-gray) for your effort.

But I realized that you should not use PageReferences in Salesforce1.

For me, the solution was very simple, I deactivated the `Available for Salesforce mobile apps` Checkbox of my VF page.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. but i can't deactivate Salesforce Mobile access to the page, as it completely hides the Edit button in Salesforce1. have you found any other workaround for the issue?