# Conditional page overriding using nooveride=1 #Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, force.com, salesforce1-app

I have to conditionally override standard Salesforce1 detail page for accounts but when I use nooverride=1, the salesforce1 still goes to the overridden page and enters an infinite loop. Can anyone put some light on why its happening and how can I fix this or is there any other approach to implement this?

I've tried navigateToURL and navigateToSObject as well but I couldn't get through.

Comment: Please post what code you have.

Comment: I posted about the same problem here and @KrisGray said it going to be fixed soon. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38458/redirect-to-standard-view-from-vf-page-with-nooverride-parameter-in-sf1

Comment: @KeithC - Did you manage to find a workaround here? I'm trapped in the same scenario. With thanks.

Comment: Did you try the following in the browser ? <SF Url>/<recordId>?nooverride=1 It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Salesforce1 effectively ignores the nooverride parameter on a url. As a result, when the user is directed to a page with "nooverride", the system just tries to override the page again, resulting in an infinite loop.  [image: Salesforce 1 and nooverride parameter]

That's the "why", but I'm unsure how to prevent this from happening. I'm trying to look into it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually type in the URL with the no override parameter = 1 does it work? It does in my sandboxes....

Thus, maybe it has to do with the `result = stdCtrl.view()`you are using.

Try constructing the URL as `'/' + obj.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/o?nooverride=1';`

and see if that works. It does in the controllers I use for this function and has never broke

It also works if using `'/' + RECORDID + '?nooverride=1'`